# Find a linear reccurrence relation where a(n) is the number of subsets of {1,2,3,...,n} not containing three consecutive numbers.

Tags: recurrence-relations

Find a **linear constant coefficient** for the recurrence relation $a(n)$ where $a(n)$ is the number of subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$  **not** containing three consecutive numbers.

So $a(n)$ must have a recurrence relation where it can be traced that the the two numbers are not greater or higher than the first?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86249/number-of-subsets-of-1-2-ldots-n-containing-no-three-consecutive-intege?rq=1 , although that question wasn't answered so I recommend leaving this one open.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A(n)$ be the number that don't include $n$.
Let $B(n)$ be the number that include $n$ but not $n-1$.
Let $C(n)$ be the number that include $n$ and $n-1$.
Find recursions for all three.

Comment: I think that's the hard way, but since Tom's assignment isn't due yet, I'll wait a while.